# Nested queries, multiple tables in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How to write the following query in eloquent or query builder in Laravel

```
SELECT *
FROM   creatives
WHERE  creative_id IN (SELECT   creative_id
                   FROM     term_relationships
                   WHERE    term_id IN (1, 2, 3)
                   GROUP BY creative_id
                   HAVING   COUNT(*) = 3)
```

My db model has the relationships defined for the above two tables. Here is are the 2 table structures

```
Table 1: creatives
creative_id       creative_name
  1                xyz
  2                pqr
  3                abc

Table 2: term_relationships
creative_id       term_id
  1                1
  1                2
  1                3
  2                1
  2                2
  2                4
```

I also need to paginate the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more complex queries and especially if you already built your sql query I recommend using the `DB::statement` function of laravel instead of eloquent.

```
DB::statement('
```

```sql
    SELECT *
    FROM   creatives
    WHERE  creative_id IN (
        SELECT   creative_id
        FROM     term_relationships
        WHERE    term_id IN (1, 2, 3)
        GROUP BY creative_id
        HAVING   COUNT(*) = 3
    )

');
```

If you really like Eloquent this could work:

```php
Creatives::WhereIn('creative_id', function($query) {
    $query->select('creative_id')
          ->from('term_relationships')
          ->whereIn('term_id', array(1, 2, 3))
          ->groupBy('creative_id')
          ->havingRaw('COUNT(*) = 3');
})->get();
```